# Ionic (AngularJS) - redirect user and routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

So I'm using Ionic for this new project, and needs a little support in routing (angular n00b).

I have these states :

```
$stateProvider.state('map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
        map: {
            templateUrl: 'views/map.html',
            controller: 'mapCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('help', {
    url: '/help',
    views: {
        help: {
            templateUrl: 'views/help.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('setname', {
    url: '/setname',
    views: {
        setname: {
            templateUrl: 'views/setname.html',
            controller: 'setNameCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

And I would like the user to be redirected to "setname" whenever he's trying to reach another page while "myName" is empty (in the future I will do something similar to check if the user is logged in before allowing access to the app).

Here is the current HTML, not sure about this at all...

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" ui-sref="map">
        <ion-nav-view name="map"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-help" ui-sref="help">
        <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Please help about this, I would appreciate it a lot.

Second question, still on routing and showing content : the base of my application will be the map. I would like the user to be able to reach it anytime very fast, so I would want it to stay available all the time in the background when displaying another page (let's say help). So whenever the user clicks a given button, it just takes him back to the map, and doesn't have to load it again. How would you advice me to do that ? I thought of using "popover" property of Ionic, but I'm not sure if it's the right way : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopover/

Thank you very much !

Comment: Ah I know why "ion navview is null". your html is messed up. take a look at this video: http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/ion-tabs-directive/. There is always ONLY one nav-view. You got 2. You need only one. Work with templates. It´s all getting explained in this video. Good look developing

Comment: OR start your project from an ionic template from your cli. Like the tabbed template.

Comment: This is from the template ^^

Comment: Looks like they changed their kind of nav-view... crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include a Service, which checks in every controller, if the myName property is true/false.
like:

```
Service.checkMyName($scope).then(function(response){
   if(!response){
      $location.path("/yourPath");
   }
});
```

A second approach:
The maybe bad way, but in my opinion way smoother is, to inject the myName property into the rootScope. So you can check on every site:

```
if(!$rootScope.myName){ $location.path("/yourPath");
```

Now the user is redirected to the page "yourPath" if the value myName is not specified.

Your second question: You should look at the [http cache option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http): The http request get executed only once. The data is cached so you the user can see it without flickering.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's working ! I used your rootscope solution, and the $state.go quicoli gave me. There is just one odd error thrown by the console, tell me if you know what this is : "TypeError: scrollView is null". It does happen only when redirecting, using $state.go or $location. Also, for the second point, I know the HTTP request is cached, but map loads in tiles, and the tiles still need to be fetched. Also, if the user is in another screen and still moving (in a bus for example), I want the map to continue working and follow him using the GPS anyway, so when he gets back to it it's already good

Comment: @JeremyBelolo To identify that TyperError you talk about, would be good to see the console output, because on it has the source of error: file(line of code)...

Comment: Firebug : "TypeError: scrollView is null
http://127.0.0.1/myApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
Line 39815" ... Chrome console : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null ionic.bundle.js:39815(anonymous function) ionic.bundle.js:39815 onPlatformReady ionic.bundle.js:2241 onWindowLoad ionic.bundle.js:2220"

Comment: Glad it helped. So you can accept this answer ;) Your second question: You could place the map into a modal. Docs here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/ . There is a $destroy function when closing the modal. Just try to not call this function. Then the modal should work in background. But take care of memory issues.

Comment: see comment in question

Answer (score 5):

for your first question
you should use $state.go, for example:

```
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
$scope.data = {};

$scope.save = function(){
        if ($scope.data.Name == ""){
            $state.go("setname");
        }

})
```

Comment: Thank you for the "$state.go" command ! If you could take a look at my comment on @m1crdy's answer, and see if you have an idea, that would be very kind of you :) Have a nice day / evening / night !